# Hangfire still points to old database even after changing the connection string

Tags: asp.net-core, hangfire

I am running Hangfire in an asp.net core application and I wanted to change the database it connects to. After changing the database, I discovered that Hangfire still connects to the old database from the logs. How do I change to the new database?

Here is my hangfire config

```
services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
            .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
            .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
            .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
            .UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HandFireCon"), new SqlServerStorageOptions
            {
                CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                UsePageLocksOnDequeue = true,
                DisableGlobalLocks = true
            }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try and use the debugger to see what value you get for method, `UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HandFireCon")`?

Most likely the config file you have for the solution still has the old DB name.

Comment: The configuration is different. I made sure I changed the database name to the old one

Comment: Have you found a solution to this ?